# Can't Do nothing (no edit, no reordering) with the Path System environment variable in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables, path

I have an issue with the %PATH% system environment variable. I get the following error message when I try to change it:

[image]

It is in french but translated in english, it would be something like

> This environment variable is too large. This dialogue box can only support parameters values up to 2047 characters

I don't think it's related to the lenght because of the following fact: if

1. I Search for and open "View advanced system settings";
2. Click the "Environment Variables" button;
3. Locate "Path" under the System variables section. Click to highlight it;
4. Click "Edit". The "Edit environment variable" modal window pops up;
5. Click "OK". Note that I did no change anything at all, no modification, not even scrolling down the mouse to see the end of the list nor reordering the list;

then I get the error message box. After Step 4 above, I need to Click "Cancel" to be able to exit.

Any idea how to handle this ?

**EDIT 1:**
The seoncd reason I think it's not related to the length is because if

1. I perform Step 1 to 4 above
2. Click on the button "Change the text", a new window pops up with the name of the variable "PATH" and its value
3. There I can delete some text/path so I have already deleted some duplicated paths in its value but then when I try Step 1 to 5 abobe, the problem is still there.

**EDIT 2**: Here is value of PATH

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mpi\intel64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32_win\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32_win\compiler;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Cuminas\Document Express DjVu Plug-in\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\HomeCloud\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.3.0\

**EDIT 3** : OK thanks guys the link was useful. Though it's weird because I don't understand why Windows allow to put more than 2047 characters in %PATH% while installing applications and then complaining months later.

Comment: If the error message is indicating your PATH variable is too long, then your PATH variable is too long, can you provide us the current value for your PATH variable?  You need to determine if the user's PATH variable is the problem or the system's PATH varaible is the problem.  Use another user to determine which variable is the problem.  Once you have collected this vital required information you should edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Thanks – Ramhound, but as I said in EDIT 1, I have already deleted some paths but the problem is still there. If it's really too long, then why can't I even just open and close the window pop up without performing any change at all  ?

Comment: Total number of chars in your case is `2200`

Cut down 153 characters. Or, create a new variable as explained in [path - Environment Variable is too large on Windows 10 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491244/environment-variable-is-too-large-on-windows-10)

Comment: @RyoSahiba - This error would not happen if your PATH varible was shoter than 2047 characters.  **By providing us your PATH varaible you have confirmed it is indeed larger then the maxium length that is allowed**  If I am not mistaken you can trick the system, by creating additional system variables, and then simply include those variables in the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to handle this ?

Your PATH variable does indeed exceed the 2047 characters that are allowed.

You can trick the system, by creating additional system variables, and then simply include those variables in the PATH variable.

You could also try and shorten any of the paths, that have a space in them, but even that might not be enough.  Your best bet is to create new system variables.

Instructions on how to include a system variable in the PATH variable can be found at [Environment Variable is too large on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491244/environment-variable-is-too-large-on-windows-10)